# How to match cell height to contents with two cells in column?

Tags: html, css

I generally wasn't able to find and solution to my problem, and as I'm quite new to HTML any help would be appreciated.

I have a HTML table on my site with the following layout:

```
|----------------------|
|                      | 
|----|------------|----|
| 1  |            |  2 |
|----|     m      |----|
| e  |            | e  |
|----|------------|----|
|                      |
|----------------------|
```

The 1 and the 2 are supposed to be contents differing in length and the e's are cells that are supposed to stay empty. M is a text block that is way longer than 1 and 2.

Now, 1 and 2 have a colored background, and I want the background to only stay behind the text. I know I could set it on a div that contains the text, but I would prefer to set it for all td's since this gives me a more unified layout, which is what I'm after.

I thought to do it by forcing the cell heights of 1 and 2 to shrink around their contents and for the e's to fill up the space below, but I can't get it to work.

[Here's a jfiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/zsdy89ub/34/) to better show my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grids. For example,

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content min-content;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: ". maincontent ." ". maincontent ." ". . .";
}

.maincontent {
  grid-area: maincontent;
}

html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container>div {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0.7rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.content-cell {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.emptyspace {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="maincontent content-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Lectus nulla at volutpat
    diam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum.
    Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem. Non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed. Amet risus nullam eget felis eget nunc. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non
    sodales neque sodales. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Nunc id cursus
    metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla.</div>
  <div class="content-cell">
    <ul>
      <li>this should shrink to fit only the list elements and no empty space</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content-cell">
    same here, this should fit only the text.
  </div>
  <div class="emptyspace"></div>
  <div class="emptyspace"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't actually do what I want, since the left and right columns still have a lot of empty space in them. Additionally I really would prefer to do this via table, because I'd have to rework quite a bit of my site.

Comment: Inside the red grid divs, you can play around with paddings, etc. to get the formatting you want. I think the easiest solution is to set the classes to the divs with the text as you mentioned if you want to work with `td`s.